# for loop different %variables (accross different operating systems)

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, variables

In the context of ffmpeg and batch file conversion/operation I've come across different variations of the for-loop which I try to understand rather than copy paste other peoples solutions.

`FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command parameter]`

Given my limited knowledge, I assume that %i, %f, %F, %G etc. all have a different function. Please understand that I work on windows and linux machines, so I guess inter-os differences also come into play. On linux systems if seen `for f`, without the %: Is this windows specific or generally a variable? Can you help me understand the different variables and their meanings? Or are they rather arbitrarily set and interchangeable?

Comment: In `bash` the value of a shell parameter `var` is `$var` or `${var}`, no `%var`

Comment: Look at the documentation of each scripting language.  Bash does not use % for variables, it uses $, like @M.NejatAydin indicated.  The  `FOR` you show in your question is Windows batch syntax.  There are a couple scripting languages that can run on both Windows and Linux, like Python, Perl, PowerShell, ...  Bash can as well, through the Windows Subsystem for Linux.  You just openned a pandora's box :)

Comment: Oh boy, I see ... Well that's the beginner's problem: You don't understand enough to ask the right questions :)

To ask very basically: What IS the scripting language? Opening the terminal in e. g. Ubuntu oder the cmd in a windows system and entering some commands I am writing in which language? Or more specifically: Which terms do I have to search for in order to find the documentations?